# Want to get entire document Using N1ql couchbase

Tags: sql++

I want to get entire document in a bucket using N1ql 
    My document Name is CR_5031_114156723_2016-08-02 where other then CR numbers will be different for different document.

```
I tried with below 2 query but getting only OrderDetails details
select d.* from Delivery.OrderDetails d where d.orderId in ['114156723']

select d.*,Delivery.OrderLines from Delivery.OrderDetails d where d.orderId in ['114156723']

Delivery is my bucket Name

Below is the document
Please help me in writing a query to get entire document

{
"OrderDetails": {
"orderId": "114156737",
"vanNumber": "5J",
"voucherPromotionName": "Computers for Schools",
"customerNumber": "85516242",
"shortOrderNumber": "4692",
"VoucherName": "Clubcard Voucher"
},
"OrderLines": {
"Product": [
{
"isApplicableForVat": "N",
"productQuantity": "6",
"productId": "52599951",
"productDescription": "Ni Pstrd S/Skimmed Milk 3ltr "
},
{
"isApplicableForVat": "Y",
"productQuantity": "1",
"productId": "55771771",
"productDescription": "Dale Farm Vanilla Ice Cream 1ltr *"
}
]
},
"DeliveryDetails": {
"deliverySlotStartTime": "20:00",
"deliverySlotEndTime": "21:00"
},
"ECoupons": {
"coupon": "0.0000"
},
"_class": "com.model.CustomerReceipt",
"OutOfStockProducts": {},

}
```

I tried with below 2 query but getting only OrderDetails details
    select d.* from Delivery.OrderDetails d where d.orderId in ['114156723']

```
select d.*,Delivery.OrderLines from Delivery.OrderDetails d where d.orderId in ['114156723']

Delivery is my bucket Name
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do this to get the full document:

select d from Delivery d where d.OrderDetails.orderId in ['114156723']